# Blender wont let me import .osm files

Tags: add-on

I downloaded the openstreetmap .osm importing addon (to let me import .osm files) and paid $5.90 for it.

I enabled the addon in user preferences yet when I go to file-import there is no option for "openstreetmap .osm" like everyone else seems to have.

This is super frustrating to me and -i don't know how to fix it. I dont wanna waste my money!

I'm using blender v2.79.

(downloaded from https://github.com/vvoovv/blender-osm/wiki/Import-OpenStreetMap-(.osm))

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a problem or bug on a commercial addon, this should be dealt with directly with the creator of the product.

Comment: The addon GUI is located on the "osm" tab of the left side panel (also known as Tool shelf and toggled with the T key) of the Blender 3D View as shown on the image
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/vvoovv/blender-osm/images/tool_shelf_osm_from_server.png (the letter "h" on the image).

Please refer to the documentation how to install and use the addon: https://github.com/vvoovv/blender-osm/wiki/Documentation#installation

Answer (score 2):

Your link brings to github page which *describes* the addon which is now commercial, and has to be paid in advance, as you said, but the addon code is not there (anymore).

After paying, you should (somehow) "get a .zip" file, and then follow instructions as here:

https://github.com/vvoovv/blender-osm/wiki/Documentation#installation

Did you follow all that and still not working? Try to close and reopen blender, just in case.

I had a previous free version, a simple .py file, and after just pasting it into the "scripts" folder, and restarting, Blender found it, and the import menu is there:

[image]

If nothing works, you should ask to the "vendor", maybe on github, adding an issue here: https://github.com/vvoovv/blender-osm/issues

Since we cannot have your .zip file, we cannot check if something is wrong with that...